# Pointer indirection issue

Tags: c++, c, pointers, gcc

This program produces 0 1 1 as output against my expected output 0 1 2. Can anybody explain why the increment operator doesn't work as prefix?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int *ptr = (int *) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        *(ptr + i) = i;

    printf("%d ", (*ptr)++);
    printf("%d ", *ptr);
    printf("%d ", *++ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BaummitAugen Yes, but the tags said C++ as well, *and the question is valid in both.* I don't think this was a valid edit; if anything, it would be better to just remove the reference to the tag (the "in C") from the title.

Comment: you want `*ptr++`. also `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: BTW, playing with the debugger would have been much faster than asking on SO.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch , yet to learn to use gdb. Thanks.

Comment: @Angew The problem I have with questions tagged for multiple languages is that even in this simple case, the answers tend to differ. If this was a C++ question it would be appropriate to tell OP not to use `<stdio.h>`, `malloc`, C-style casts. This obviously does not apply to a c question.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Yes of course. Normally, I would be the first one to suggest "don't use C-isms in C++." The thing is that here, the question and answer are actually valid for both, and the question itself does not depend on the output (or memory allocation) method. I can't see why a search for "[c++] pointer indirection" should be made to not find this.

Comment: @Angew Ok, thanks, I agree with that. Added tag again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume that `int *p = ptr`:

```
printf("%d ", (*ptr)++);  // print ptr[0] then increment ptr[0] ==> 0
printf("%d ", *ptr);      // print ptr[0] ==> 1
printf("%d ", *++ptr);    // increment ptr then effectively print p[1] ==> 1
```

Answer (score 3):

`*++ptr` is equivalent to `*(++ptr)`: increment `ptr` and then dereference the incremented pointer. `++(*ptr)` in third `printf` will give the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
    printf("%d ", (*ptr)++);
```

You are incrementing the number `*ptr` which is inside the memory location `ptr`; you don't touch the pointer `ptr` itself.

Before that `printf`, `ptr[0]` contained 0. You incremented it.

Answer (score 1):

How about ++(*ptr)? That's a better equivalent of your postfix on the first of the three lines.

Your original code is doing *(++ptr) effectively, which isn't what you were looking for no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because by doing:
`*++ptr` you increament the pointer ptr and not the value of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The address stored in pointer is remains same until the program termination.
 These two statements `printf("%d ", (*ptr)++);     printf("%d ", *++ptr);` increments the value stored in ptr. 1st statement is post increment and 2nd is preinrement `

To increment address you can use ++ptr.